# Multiple files/ZIP sending as email attachments

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I am creating a blackberry application using phonegap/cordova where I have to take multiple images with camera and send them as email. I am able to take pictures, but my question is **how can I send multiple files as attachment in blackberry**. I know I can send a single file as attachment.

**OR**

How to make a zip file with all the files to attach and send that

PS: My files are an excel sheet which is in xml format(.xls) and multiple images